# Android mediator live data combine 2 live data into one stream and one trigger

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, mediatorlivedata

I have 2 live data, I add them as sources to a mediator live data, I expose this from a view model for a fragment to observe.

When either of the live data changes it triggers the onChanged method of the mediator live data, which means my observer gets triggered twice, what I want is to combine the two and observe just one stream that only triggers once, is there something I'm missing or do I need to roll my own method for this? currently I do this, which triggers twice

**SOME CODE REMOVED FOR BREVITY**

```
public CardViewModel(@NonNull Application application , int clicks, String[] cardArgs){
    sentenceRepository = new SentenceRepository(application);
    cards = Transformations.switchMap(search, mySearch -> sentenceRepository.searchLiveCardListByWordTypeAndWordDescriptionAndSearchWord(cardArgs[0],cardArgs[1],mySearch));
    groupRepository = new GroupRepository(application);
    groups = groupRepository.getGroupsByWordDescriptionAndWordType(cardArgs[0],cardArgs[1]);
    sentencesAndGroups = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    sentencesAndGroups.addSource(cards, sentences -> {
        Log.d(TAG,"addSource cards");
        sentencesAndGroups.setValue(combineLatest(sentences, groups.getValue()));
    });

    sentencesAndGroups.addSource(groups, groupsWithSentences -> {
        Log.d(TAG,"addSource groups");
        sentencesAndGroups.setValue(combineLatest(cards.getValue(), groupsWithSentences));
    });

}

private List<Visitable> combineLatest(List<Sentence> sentenceList, List<GroupsWithSentences> groupsWithSentences) {
    List<Visitable> visitableList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (sentenceList != null){
        visitableList.addAll(sentenceList);
    }
    if (groupsWithSentences != null){
        visitableList.addAll(groupsWithSentences);
    }
    return visitableList;
}
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BiFunction`. In my project I have a class which contains this:

```
public class MultipleLiveDataTransformation {
    @MainThread
    public static <X, Y, O> LiveData<O> biMap(LiveData<X> data1, LiveData<Y> data2, final BiFunction<X, Y, O> biFun) {
        final MediatorLiveData<O> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        result.addSource(data1, x -> result.setValue(biFun.apply(x, data2.getValue())));
        result.addSource(data2, y -> result.setValue(biFun.apply(data1.getValue(), y)));

        return result;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
public LiveData<Visitable> getVisitables() {
    return MultipleLiveDataTransformation.biMap(groups, sentences, (gro, sen) -> {
        List<Visitable> visitableList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (gro != null) {
            visitableList.addAll(gro);
        }
        if (sen != null) {
            visitableList.addAll(sen);
        }
        return visitableList;
    });
}
```

I do not fully understand what lists you have and what you want to observe. The example I gave here can observe two `LiveData` objects and triggers when one of them needs to update. It will always give you the most up to date version of the `Visitable` objects.

If I don't understand the problem, can you explain what `LiveData` objects need to be combined and what the result needs to be?

In the case, that an extra `LiveData` object needs to be observed in the `MultipleDataTransformation`, it is possible to make a `triMap`.

Edit: 
You can try this:

```
public LiveData<Visitable> getVisitables() {
    return MultipleLiveDataTransformation.biMap(groups, sentences, (gro, sen) -> {
        List<Visitable> visitableList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (gro != null && !gro.isEmpty() && sen != null && !sen.isEmpty()) {
            visitableList.addAll(gro);
            visitableList.addAll(sen);
        }
        return visitableList;
    });
}
```

Comment: the problem here is that it updates everytime the most recent live data emits a value so it will always trigger twice, because the live data will never complete at the same time, what i want is maybe a check to see if one has completed and then a timeout to tell the live data whether it should complete and emit a value or wait for the other live data to complete, because i only want one stream like throttle works on rxjava

Comment: Then I don't think this will fit your problem. This will trigger if e.g. groups or sentences is updated. What you can do is return an empty list in the biMap if `groups` or `sentences` is empty. If they are both filled, you can combine them and return the full List. You can call getVisitables() and check if the list is not empty before updating.

Comment: yh thats not a bad idea